# NIO: Written bytes never reach the receiver

Tags: java, nio, proc

I'm developing a Java library to exchange data using NIO. Is it possible that my client writes something into a socket and close it and the server accepts the connection but never reads those bytes because the read method returns -1?

In my case is the client side that after writting on the socket, closes the connection. I leave here the log of the problem that I'm having. As you can see 379 bytes are written on the client-end of the socket but never received on the server.

Client Log

```
43:32.335- OPENING SOCKET 1480207683
43:32.976- FINISH CONNECTION for socket@1480207683 -> Socket[addr=/10.20.0.10,port=43000,localport=45002]
43:32.976- Socket 1480207683 has written 379 bytes
43:33.445- Closing socket 1480207683
```

Server Log

```
43:32.766: ACCEPT for socket@816266612 -> Socket[address=/172.16.8.251,port=45002,localPort=43000]
43:33.641 D/Comm: Socket 816266612 has read -1 bytes
43:33.644 D/Comm: Closing socket 816266612...
```

Which options do I have to ensura that this communication works? Shall I wait until the server closes its end to close the client's? Or  is there any other method to ensure that once written in the socket, the message should arrive whatever the network does with it?

Here is the code for the write and read methods (I've simplified it because it does some processing after receiving the bytes that's not interesting at all). It works for 99% of the communications I'm doing and simple cases. The problem raises when dealing with many concurrent communications .

```
private void read(SelectionKey key) {
    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    // Read data from the socket
    ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(NIOProperties.PACKET_SIZE);
    int size = sc.read(readBuffer);
    LOGGER.info("Socket " + sc.hashCode() + " has read " + size + " bytes");
    if (size == -1) {
        closeChannel(key, sc);
        return;
    }
    readBuffer.flip();
    process(readBuffer);
}

private void write(SelectionKey key) {
    if (writeBuffer != null) {
        if (writeBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
            int written = sc.write(writeBuffer);
            LOGGER.info("Socket " + sc.hashCode() + " has written " + written + " bytes");
        }
        changeInterest(sc, SelectionKey.OP_READ);          
    }
}
```

Comment: show your write code.

Comment: And pls show your read code as well. I have the feeling that it's the last read you're writing to the log which would return -1 on the end of the stream.

Comment: I updated the question with the code. However, it's more a teoretical thing about if that could happen or not depending on the network conditions

Comment: You might check `key.isValid()`

Comment: What would that change? Does isValid check some sort of sequence number or something?
As far as I know the socket could only read -1 when the socket is closed and there's no more data to read from the socket's internal buffer. Even if I check the key validity I wouldn't receive the data.

Comment: @JoopEggen If the key wasn't valid, `key.channel()` would fail for a start.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that my client writes something into a socket and close it and the server accepts the connection but never reads those bytes because the read method returns -1?

No. All data will be read before `read()` returns -1. TCP guarantees it.

If this is a high-concurrency problem I suspect something is `static` that shouldn't be `static`, or a member variable where it should be a local variable. Socket channels for example, or selection keys, or buffers.

NB You don't need to pass the key to `closeChannel()`. You don't even need the method, unless it logs something. `channel.close()` is sufficient.

Comment: That's what I had understood. Even if there's a static/member variable, the 379 bytes that were sent should be received by the socket reader. ACCEPT and FINISH CONNECTION are printing the hashcode of the socket and the toString value, so its the same socket.

Comment: I've just seen that I don't enable the keepAlive flag on the server side. If the network is really congested, could that explain it?